# How to avoid duplicate slugs based on 2 tables and create unique slug

Tags: php, mysql, slug

I am working for a private website. I have 2 tables:

Table A (contain older slugs).

Table B (new slugs).

Here the code for checking exist slug and creating unique slugs from table B (single table query) and this is running good

```
 <?php  
  $target = "SELECT COUNT(`slug`) FROM `table B` WHERE `slug`='$slug'";
  $query= mysqli_query($kkdb, $target);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);  
  return ($row[0] == 1) ? true : false;
  }
  ?>
```

for checking exist slugs it will create new and unique slug;

```
  <?php  
   $slug = $oslug;
   $count = 1;
   while (slug_exist($slug)) {
   $slug =$oslug.'-'.$count++;
   ?>
```

> My question, how to checking exist slugs from both tables (table A dan table B) and creating unique slugs which are not exist in both tables?
>
> let me know if you are not sure what I'm taking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a view AB, that is a UNION ALL of tables A and B slug values. If creating a view is unavailable to you, you can use the UNION ALL syntax in-line in the $target.

That said - you will need to adjust the return assertion because you may return a count of 2, even if slug exists as a primary key in both tables.

```
return ($row[0] >= 1) ? true : false;
```

Edit - explanation of "view AB":

Say you have

TableA (slug varchar(100) primary key), and
TableB (slug varchar(100) primary key)

then

```
CREATE VIEW ViewAB AS
   SELECT a.slug FROM TableA a
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.slug FROM TableB b;
```

And instead of your php code referencing either TableA or TableB, have it reference ViewAB.

Comment: wow.. It works, Mr. O'Neill thanks for your help.... may god bless you..